# Run query inside a function

Tags: php, mysql, function

I have searched everywhere without behing able to figure out the right way forward.

In my controller.php I have:

```
<?php $get_listing = function ($id) {
$results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM listings ORDER BY date DESC");
$listings = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} ?>
```

Above is my function for retrieving data from the database. I want to retrieve a specific row based on the variable $id.

Now, in my ad-details.php, I have:

```
<?php foreach(get_listing($id) as $info) {
echo $info["price"]; }
```

I get an error message saying that the function get_listing is undefined, which is strange because the controller.php is included in the ad-details.php

Any ideas guys? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

2 errors:

1 - You forgot

```
global $db;
```

and the return statement in your function.

2 - If you use [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), you need to call them with $ sign. Probably

```
<?php 
   foreach($get_listing($id) as $info) {
       echo $info["price"]; 
   }
?>
```

is working.

Answer (score 0):

You've set your function to a variable named `$get_listing`, but call it with `get_listing`.

Either declare your function like this.

```
function get_listing($id)
```

Or call it like this.

```
$get_listing($id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function get_listing($id)
  {
    $results  = $db->query("SELECT * FROM listings ORDER BY date DESC");
    $listings = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }
?>
```